# How to suppress specific CSS 2.0 validation errors in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, css

A typical CSS property that I use often is `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`. Sometimes I use CSS 2.1 or later properties or selectors. These (correctly) raise a validation error:

> `Validation (CSS 2.0): 'overflow-y' is not a known CSS property name.`

For years I ignored this, but it kinda feels wrong. It's possible to switch off warnings in C# and other languages for a particular line, block, file or project. Is something similar possible for CSS (or HTML) errors or warnings? Instead of switching it all off, I prefer a more granular solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it's all or nothing in VS 2008...yes it really sucks.

Comment: Isn't there something like an event sink, like `OnReportError` or whatever that I could bind to through a home-grown addin and then ignore only a specific list?

Comment: @Nick: glad you've finally been proven wrong, see new answer of Carl below ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're willing to muck around a bit you can get exactly what you want.

1. Go to Visual Studio folder \Common7\Packages\1033\schemas\CSS
2. Copy css21.xml to css21mod.xml
3. Find the section:

   ```
   <cssmd:property-def _locID="overflow" ...
   ```
4. After that section, insert:

   ```
   <cssmd:property-def 
       _locID="overflow-x" _locAttrData="description,syntax" 
       type="enum" 
       description="Visibility of content extending beyond element's dimensions in x"
       syntax="One of the overflow values | inherit" 
       enum="inherit auto hidden scroll visible"/>

   <cssmd:property-def 
       _locID="overflow-y" _locAttrData="description,syntax" type="enum" 
       description="Visibility of content extending beyond element's dimensions in y" 
       syntax="One of the overflow values | inherit" 
       enum="inherit auto hidden scroll visible"/>
   ```
5. Open regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Packages\{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas`

   If on 64-bit, you will have to go to `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft` etc
6. Create a new key called `Schema 5`, and fill in the "File" and "Friendly Name" string values with `css21mod.xml` and `CSS 2.1 (mod)`

Should be all set!

Comment: Excellent solution! I sure hoped it was possible to extend CSS validation, and this surely shows how to. Thanks! (PS: don't copy/paste tab characters, they don't work, replace them with spaces)

Comment: If you just want to turn the invalid properties warnings off, and you feel like you don't need to be informed if ever you type in one wrong, Tools->Options->Text Editor->CSS->Misc->Uncheck:Detect Unknown Properties - I didn't want to submit this as an answer as I would never want it to supersede the above, but I do feel people should know about this option.

Answer (score 8):

Hi I just discovered this. In Visual Studio 2010 SP1 there is support for HTML5 validation.

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation`

Now personally because I hate VS telling me I have duplicate ID's(Which is fine for non server controls) I turn off all warnings and set my validation to XHTML5 (Which is an option).

You can however tweak the settings till your hearts content. Sadly this is not project specific and other team members will need to do the same.

Comment: I don't have the option for XHTML5. But regardless, the other options do not allow you to suppress specific CSS 2.0 validation errors, only all (of a certain kind) or none. And many types cannot be suppressed at all, only switched on or off completely.

Comment: I am not sure where I got my XHTML5 validation from but it fixes issues with CSS3 validations I have had warnings for. And yes sadly its either on or off.

Comment: If you are comfortable with your xhtml / css abilities then its quite safe to turn these off.

Answer (score 3):

[How to make Visual Studio stop "compiling" .js and .css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125455/how-to-make-visual-studio-stop-compiling-js-and-css-files)

Comment: Thanks, but that question is related, but not equal to this one: I want to ignore specific warnings (as you can do in C# for instance for warnings). Switching off warnings of CSS completely is not what I'm after (see last line in my q.).

Answer (score 2):

Similarly as Jeremy Child suggested, but specific for Visual studio 2008 (as specified in the opriginal question):

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> CSS Specific : uncheck
>   "Detect unknown properties"

This removes all CSS validation. This is a good solution if you need the problem to disappear fast (I have no time/bit lazy to manually add each property in an xml file and check the windows registry...) and if you are good in CSS (validation not really needed when you use built-in intellisense or styles that you are sure work -e.g. taken from previous websites you did-).

Answer (score 1):

Get support for CSS 3.0 in order to suppress some of the warnings:

[how to make visualstudio 2008 support css v3 & html v5](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/312405/how-to-make-visualstudio-support-css-v-html)

[CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210)

Answer (score -1):

So this is what happened to me. I had a successfully working project. I made a copy and started working on some label changes. And I started getting 
"Validation (CSS 2.0): 'overflow-y' is not a known CSS property name."

The above error kept appearing even after reopening the projects.

So I went back to my original project, opened, started debugging to see if I get that error in that project also. The project successfully. Stopped there. Came to my new error throwing project, and now the error is no longer there.

Something to think about what caused it go away. Something in a memory. May be

Comment: For me, the CSS errors go away if the related files are not open in the editor. When you see the errors and you close the files, the CSS errors disappear.