# Prevent CSS Validation for just 1 line

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem practically identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125455/how-to-make-visual-studio-stop-compiling-js-and-css-files), but I'm looking for a different solution. Instead of turning it off globally, I'd like to just disable it for a single line. I know I have seen many examples where various techniques are used to suppress different warnings, and I am looking for one that I can put in my CSS to suppress this one.

Examples of ways to suppress warnings and such `#pragma warning disable 659` or `[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors",
            Justification = "I have a good reason.")]`.

The CSS I want it to be quiet about has some CSS3 stuff in it which is why it's understandably complaining:

```
.round
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

So any idea how to make my `Error 1 Validation (CSS 2.1): 'border-radius' is not a known CSS property name` error go away? I'd rather not lose all of my CSS validations but I do want it to ignore this one "problem".

Comment: I just unselected "Detect unknown properties" and left "Detect invalid values" so I still get some validation. It is unfortunate though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that its possible. But you could separate the nice effect from the basic ones.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/22/progressive-enhancement-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/
Make a style sheet for all the cool css3.0 stuff. Add-it to browser that can use it. For those that cant (ie, who else), you give the only the basic styleSheet.
So real browser got basic + css3.0. IE get basic only.