# Removing "Design-time-lock" attribute from legacy code

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm converting a project from .net 1.1 to 3.5, and everywhere the following is used in the markup:

```
Design_Time_Lock: true
```

e.g.

`<asp:linkbutton id="lbRun" style="Z-INDEX: 111;  Design_Time_Lock: True" runat="server">Run</asp:linkbutton>`

I get the following error:

> "Validation (CSS 2.0): 'Design' is not
>   a known CSS property name"

I've [read up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730784%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about the `Design_Time_Lock` attribute, and I can see when it will and won't be generated. However I don't really understand the point of it. And- more importantly- can all instances of it be safely removed throughout the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style is only used by Visual Studio to lock the position of a control so that you can't move the control around in design view. You can leave it or remove it, it will not cause any specifik harm to remove it. More than it's then possible to move around the control in the design view.

Se more:
**Aligning and Layering HTML Elements in Design View**
*Visual Studio .NET 2003*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730784(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: check out this answer on how to disable the errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125455/how-to-make-visual-studio-stop-compiling-js-and-css-files