# Support for Javascript template markup when editing HTML files in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio

I have some HTML files that are loaded by Javascript and used to render content using underscore.js templates. They include markup like the following:

```
<div class="subitem <%= (i==0 ? "first" : "") %>" data-cid="<%=model.cid %>" >
```

When I edit the HTML files in Visual Studio 2010, it doesn't cope too well with the <% %> and <%= %> template tags. For example, there are several squigglies in the above markup ("unknown css class i", "unexpected token" etc). The same problem applies with tags used by other template libraries, such as Mustache and JQuery Templates which use curly braces for their tags.

I'd like the editor to ignore any code within the template tags. Is there a way of configuring Visual Studio to do this, or a plug-in that solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For mustache and jquery template, create them in `<script>` tag, then set the `type` attribute to other than that of javascript. For jquery template:

```
<script id="userTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <option value="{{=UserID}}">{{=FullName}}</option>
</script>
<script id="deptTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <option value="{{=DepartmentID}}">{{=DepartmentName}}</option>
</script>
```

Then you may extract the content like this

```
$("#userTemplate").html() // to get the content
```

As for `<%`, I currently do not know how to make VS ignore it, though I doubt it.

**Update**

Well, since you're using underscore.js, why not change the `_.templateSettings` [to use another symbol](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm really after a way of dealing with cases where a single html file is the entire template. As for changing the symbols, the same problem applies with tags like {{ }} I'm afraid.

Comment: Were you refering to compiler warnings?

Comment: The warnings are shown in the Visual Studio HTML Editor because the template tags mean that the document is invalid HTML.

Comment: Hmm, so you're looking for ways [to disable compiler warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125455/how-to-make-visual-studio-stop-compiling-js-and-css-files)? The instructions applies for HTML type.

Comment: I'd prefer it if it would just ignore parts in the template tags and validate the rest of the HTML as normal. Probably too much to ask though ;)

Comment: Yeah, it appears to fall under a "plug in" type to support template. :)

Comment: Thanks!  Currently VS (or one of my plugins) recognizes that script type and does exactly the right thing with it.