# List not rendering in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am a newby to underscore.js, I'm expecting the following to render the list passed to it but instead it renders this :

```
Title: {{title}}
Author: {{author}}
```

heres a snippet:

```
<script src="/Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
    <script id="tmpl-books" type="text/template">
        <ul>
            <li>Title: {{title}}</li>
            <li>Author: {{author}}</li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                var list =
                [
                    {
                        "title": "Myst: The Book of Atrus",
                        "author": "Rand Miller"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "The Hobbit",
                        "author": "J.R.R. Tolkien"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Stardust",
                        "author": "Neil Gaiman"
                    }
                ];

       $(document).ready(function () { 
            var tmplMarkup = $('#tmpl-books').html();
            var compiledTmpl = _.template(tmplMarkup, list);
            $('#rendered').html(compiledTmpl);
     });
</script>
```

---

In the Html body I have a div with the id="rendered"

```
<html> 
 <body>
  <div id="rendered"></div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly-braces are the Mustache.js style.  Underscore uses the `<%= %>` syntax:

```
<li>Title: <%= title %></li>
```

Also, the Underscore.js template expects the names "title", etc, to be in the object-map you pass.  You can't pass an array, as far as I know.  Instead, wrap the array in "items" like this:

```
var list = { items: [ ... ] };
```

And use a template that iterates over them:

```
 <% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
    <ul>
        <li>Title: <%= item.title %></li>
        <li>Author: <%= item.author %></li>
    </ul>
 <% }); %>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrkjn/12/)

Comment: I get a compilation error when I attempt :<li>Title: <%= title %></li>

Comment: If I try using the templateSettings interpolate, its says that "title" not defined.

Comment: @Fabii sorry, I completely missed that you were using an array.  See my updated answer, with demo.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I didn't look at your answer, just did some reading on Underscorejs.org.  I'm not sure about that approach, though, except for simple templates -- for example, I don't think it would work with script blocks?

Comment: @McGarnagle, yeah you are right it does not work with the script blocks.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit hasty in accepting this answer. I am running my code is VS 2012 , its seems to be get a runtime compilation error  on this line:  <% _.each(items, function(item) { %> . Can not resolve symbol.

Comment: I think I need to add : _.templateSettings = {
            interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,      // print value: {{ value_name }}
            evaluate: /\{%([\s\S]+?)%\}/g,   // excute code: {% code_to_execute %}
            escape: /\{%-([\s\S]+?)%\}/g
        };

Comment: @Fabii that's really a problem with Visual Studio's HTML parser -- it doesn't recognize the templating stuff.  Not sure if there's a good solution to this, other than just don't use VS to edit templated HTML.  Similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8134707/1001985

Comment: Problem solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703874/templatesettings-not-working/18704142?noredirect=1#18704142

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to use "mustache-style" template syntax, instead of underscore's.  Underscore does let you use mustache-style though, see the docs at: http://underscorejs.org/#template, in particular the following block of code:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
template({name: "Mustache"});
```

Comment: For my example, if  I use the mustache-style  and _.templateSettings, I get a title not defined error, is my list syntax correct?

Comment: Sorry I've never configured underscore to use mustache style templates....have you tried using underscore's built-in templating?