# How to evaluate javascript functions in underscore with mustache notation?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, templating, underscore.js-templating

I want to do something like this:

```
<script id="tmpl-books" type="text/template">
  <ul>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) { %>
      <% var book = books[i]; %>
      <li>
      <em><%= book.title %></em> by <%= book.author %>
      </li>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</script>
```

in my code, but I am using JSP so I have to use the {{ }} notation, but when I do this {{ for(var... }} does not work.

```
<script id="tmpl-books" type="text/template">
      <ul>
        {{ for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) { }}
          <% var book = books[i]; %>
          <li>
          <em>{{= book.title }}</em> by {{ book.author }}
          </li>
        {{ } }}
      </ul>
    </script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do your `_.templateSettings` look like?

Comment: _.templateSettings = {
 interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underscore templates have [three distinct regexes](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Define an **interpolate** regex to match expressions that should be interpolated verbatim, an **escape** regex to match expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an **evaluate** regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without insertion into the resulting string.

If you want to use Handlebars-ish delimiters, you'll want to define all three rather than just the `interpolate` regex:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    escape: /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Also note that the `interpolate` and `escape` regexes must match things that `evaluate` won't due to [the order that the regexes are applied in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704142/479863).

With those template settings, a template like this:

```
<script id="tmpl-books" type="text/template">
    <ul>
        {{ for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) { }}
            {{ var book = books[i]; }}
            <li>
                <em>{{= book.title }}</em> by {{= book.author }}
           </li>
        {{ } }}
    </ul>
</script>
```

should work. Note the change from `{{ book.author }}` to `{{= book.author }}` since you're interpolating `book.author`, not evaluating it.

Comment: would that be {{ var book = books[i] }} because the <% is going to call jsp.

Comment: Sorry, missed that `var`, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience the best way is to override the three regexes distinctly like that:

```js
_.templateSettings.evaluate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g;
_.templateSettings.escape = /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g;
```

without replacing the entire object `_.templateSettings` like that:

```js
_.templateSettings = {
  evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
  interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
  escape: /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g,
};
```