# Creating the submenus with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, submenu

New in using Backbone.js and underscore.js, trying to create a list of submenus (second level) for my menulist (first level).

So this is my menulist I created in JSON (which I have confirmed exists by printing it to the browser console):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Sök kund",
    "path": 
    [
      {
        "subName": "Fondkonto",
        "subPath": "#fondkonto"
      },

      {
        "subName": "Kassakonto",
        "subPath": "#kassakonto"
      },

      {
        "subName": "Nytt sparande",
        "subPath": "#nyttsparande"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "Ny kund",
    "path": "#new_customer"
  },
    {
    "name": "Dokument",
    "path": "#documents"
  },

  {
    "name": "Blanketter",
    "path": "#forms"
  }
]
```

And this is the code I put out to show in my index-file, which for now prints only the first-level:

```
<script type="text/template" id="menus">
  {{ _.each(menus, function(menu) { }}
    <li><a href="{{= menu.path }}">{{= menu.name }}</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="{{= menu.path.subPath }}">{{= menu.path.subName }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  {{ }); }}
</script>
```

And in case you want to know how the view and model/collection are built:

```
var Menus = require("../collections/menus");

var AllMenus = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: "#menuContent",

  template: _.template(document.getElementById("menus").innerHTML),

  initialize: function() {

    "use strict";

    this.menus = new Menus();
    this.listenTo(this.menus, "reset", this.render);

    this.menus.fetch({
      reset: true,
      url: "./data/menus.json",
      success: function() {
        console.log("Succesfully loaded menus.json file.");
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("There was some error trying to load and process menus.json file.");
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log( this.menus.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(this.template({ menus: this.menus.toJSON() }));
    return this;
  }

});

var viewMenus = new AllMenus();
```

Model:

```
var Menu = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: "",
    path: ""
  }
});

module.exports = Menu;
```

Collection:

```
var Menu = require("../models/menu");

var Menus = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Menu
});

module.exports = Menus;
```

Don't mean to paste so much code, but necessary to make this so you understand how I built it up. But I got stuck by trying to show my subMenus with no success to it.

Comment: Sometimes your menu.path is a string and sometimes it's an array. When it's an array  you have to use `menu.path[n].subName` notation. [See here for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/3585500). Your template will to have to test what `menu.path` is and either print it or _.each it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is wrong. You do not want to be switching between Strings and Arrays for your `path` value. A `path` should always be a String, and you should create a new property to hold the submenu Array; "submenu" would be a good name. Furthermore, your submenu items should not have `subName` and `subPath` as key names. These objects are conceptually the same as their parent objects and they should have the same keys, `name` and `path`.

Your revised data structure should look like the following:

```
var menus = [
    {
        "name": "Sök kund",
        "path": "#",
        "submenu": [
            {
                "name": "Fondkonto",
                "path": "#fondkonto"
            },
            {
                "name": "Kassakonto",
                "path": "#kassakonto"
            },
            {
                "name": "Nytt sparande",
                "path": "#nyttsparande"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Ny kund",
        "path": "#new_customer",
        "submenu": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Dokument",
        "path": "#documents",
        "submenu": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Blanketter",
        "path": "#forms",
        "submenu": []
    }
];
```

Next, we will update your template to iterate through the top level menu items *and*, conditionally, their submenus:

```
<script type="text/template" id="menus">
    {{ _.each(menus, function(menu) { }}
        <li>
            <a href="{{= menu.path }}">{{= menu.name }}</a>
            {{ if (menu.submenu && menu.submenu.length > 0) { }}
                <ul>
                    {{ _.each(menu.submenu, function (submenu) { }}
                        <li><a href="{{= submenu.path }}">{{= submenu.name }}</a></li>
                    {{ }); }}
                </ul>
            {{ } }}
        </li>
    {{ }); }}
</script>
```

Note: I assume you are doing something like the following to tell Underscore to override the default template settings with a Mustache-style syntax. I copied these settings from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21665595/3397771).

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    escape: /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g 
};
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I finished this. And yeah it looked like you mentioned.