# How to disable JavaScript build error in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, eslint

I just updated Visual Studio 2017 from RC to final. I didn’t get the following error but recently I get this error. In building the project, I get the following error and it prevents the web project to start:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   eqeqeq  (ESLint) Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.   VistaBest.Shop.Web  C:\***\Request.js   21
```

[image: JavaScript Error]

How can I disable JavaScript building error in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: It's not my code problem, I want to use '==' instead of '===' in my JavaScript code

Comment: JavaScript error not should prevent building MVC project in Visual Studio

Comment: Either share your code, or disable the javascript error message - read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125455/how-to-make-visual-studio-stop-compiling-js-and-css-files

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 there isn't `Show syntax errors` in Tools > Options

Comment: @Koby Douek: It's not my code problem, I don't want to build error for JavaScript file in Visual Studio

Comment: I would particularly be interested in disabling this specific error. `==` is as valid a comparison operator as '==='. For me it doesn't prevent me from building, it just clutters up the error list when I have another error in my server code.

Comment: what about vice-versa? I need build errors based on ESLint rules, how can I configure this?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

I think, find the solution:

1. Open `Tools > Options`
2. Navigate to `Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > EsLint` (in VS2017 15.8 it is `Linting` not `EsLint`)
3. Set `Enable ESLint` to `False`

[image: Disable ESlint]

Visual Studio >= 15.8.5
[image: Disable ESlint Visual Studio 15.8.5]

Comment: Worked for me in VS2017

Comment: quick tip: the text box on the top left in screenshot can be used to search for any setting/option easily!

Comment: This didn't exactly work quite the same way in 15.8.0 - it's hidden under `Linting>General` Searching for `eslint` will still bring it up, but it will be labeled linting. See @Brad's answer below.

Comment: This feature automatically started to work after the update to VS 2017 15.8.1. I had to turn it off again manually.

Comment: Thanks! That was pissing me off. For version 15.8.5 is just a checkbox now.

Answer (score 43):

## In Visual Studio 2017 (v 15.8.0):

## Option 1: Options > JS Errors

1. Open `Tools > Options`
2. Navigate to `Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Code Validation`
3. Set `Enable JavaScript errors` to `false`
4. or, set `Enable JavaScript errors` to `true` and `Show errors as warnings` to `true`

***I needed to restart Visual Studio for this to take effect.***

[image: Options > JS Errors]

## Option 2: Options > Linting

There is another option below which will let you edit your global linting settings:

[image: Options > JS Linting]

## Option 3: .eslint file

You can also create a file named `.eslintrc` in the root of your project.

## Option 4: ESLint commands in-file

[See @user9153924's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48026234/444382)

---

## Resources

- [ESLint file syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration)
- [ESLint Rules](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/)

Answer (score 16):

I tried Mohammad`s solution but it didn't work. I managed to work doing the following:

1. Righ click on your web .csproj file
2. On the first `<PropertyGroup>` add the following entry:
   `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>`

Comment: I think you missed a couple steps there. Did you mean right click your web .csproj, unload project, right click it again, edit?

Answer (score 11):

Add `/*eslint eqeqeq: ["error", "smart"]*/` to the first line of your Javascript code to remove the errors.
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq

Following Mohammad's solution will turn off ESLint for syntax checking. This works in VS2015 and should work in later versions.

Comment: Perfect & doesn't throw the baby out with the bathwater

Comment: Thank you!   This worked, but I am pretty sure that "error" should be "off" or 0 (zero, no quotes).     I also got a package.json file to work thanks to the URL reference.

Answer (score 4):

**For Visual Studio 2019.**

[image]

1. Open Tools > Options
2. Navigate to Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript
3. => Linting > General.

Then unchecked ESLint check box.
Please The bellow Image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've just had to change the **"eqeqeq"** rule behaviour to include "smart":

Edit the .eslintrc file found in your user root folder mentioned in other answers already.

The change is made to the **rules** section by adding the smart rule

```
    "rules": {

    "eqeqeq": [2, "smart"],
```

*Copied from the web article:*
This option enforces the use of === and !== except for these cases:

1. Comparing two literal values
2. Evaluating the value of typeof
3. Comparing against null

I found the specifics at:
https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/eqeqeq

Comment: Thank you!  I had to close and reopen Visual Studio for the change to take effect.  Also, adding in the "smart" parameter didn't seem to clear the error in all cases, however removing the rule altogether did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Mohammad's solution but with no luck, I followed Rafeel answer and instead of adding his suggested code sample I removed below code from `web .csproj` and finally I was able to build and run my project. There were two places where you should remove that in the same file. Still, I don't have any clue how the removed code will affect my solution.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```

Hope this will also help someone to save the day..!!!