# How do I turn off JSLint in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, jslint

I loaded up an older aspnet mvc project in Visual Studio 2017, and I can't build it because thousands of warnings/errors from jslint are telling me that the jQuery package has bad bracket placement, among many other things.  Frankly, I don't care about any of the errors from jslint, least of all the jQuery errors.

I can't find any options for jslint in the GUI.

- Right-clicking on the project gives no jslint context menu
- It doesn't seem to exist in `Tools > Options`
- I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724820/how-to-disable-javascript-build-error-in-visual-studio-2017), of turning off EsLint, but that did nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLint.Net is a NuGet package.  You can configure it via a [JSLintNet.json settings file](https://github.com/benquarmby/jslintnet/wiki/JSLint.NET-Settings) (at the end of that page it says there's a settings dialog, but I can't find it in either VS 2015 or VS 2017.)  Or you can uninstall the package thru the `Project > Manage NuGet Packages...` menu.

Comment: That's the solution I had to do, was uninstall the package.  I wish it wasn't so aggressive with errors, but oh well.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about VS2015 or 2017, but in 2019 the settings file JSLintNet.json can be created in the project folder and then you can set

"runOnBuild": false,
"cancelBuild": false

Here's my complete file:

```
{
  "ignore": [
  "\\www\\js-lib\\*.*"
],
"options": {
 "predef": {
  "$": true,
  "document": true,
  "login": true,
  "setup": true,
  "window": true,
  "popup": true
 },
 "plusplus": true,
 "unparam": true,
 "white": true
},
"output": "Warning",
"runOnSave": true,
"runOnBuild": false,
"cancelBuild": false
}
```