# 64 Error in jquery.validate-vsdoc.js file in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC project and realized that Visual Studio is reporting errors in the jquery.validate-vsdoc.js file and I'm not sure what this file might impact on my application.

Most of the errors are for reasons of relational operators "==" "!="

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This errors are related to JSLint. 
JSLint is a javascript quality code tool and you can avoid this errors.

You can have a look to this thread if you want to know how to configure JSLint in Visual Studio.

[How do I turn off JSLint in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400595/how-do-i-turn-off-jslint-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the operators "==" or "!=" cause an implicit conversion.

Example:

```
var str0 = "0";
var int0 = 0;

console.log(str0 == int0); // true;
console.log(str0 === int0); // false;
```

You should use non-implicit conversion operators.